# Do threads/processes that create/delete files/directories under a shared parent dir interfere?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, filesystems, process, parallel-processing

I was wondering: If I have a directory `/a/b/c/` and under `c` X threads create subdirectories and files and delete them (they are temporary directories and files as intermediate steps of processing) do the X threads/processes somehow interfere with each other?  E.g. lock one another or some other side-effect?
To be clear: Except the parent directory `/a/b/c/` no other directory/file is shared among any process. Under this parent directory each creates temporary unique directories and files and deletes them after a while.
Also is there any benefit to using a specific version of HD for such kind of operations?

Comment: as your threads create unique dir/files, there is no issue. The concurrent access to the file system is also true for multi-process interactions. What do you mean with "specific version of HD"? file-system type?

Comment: @tonioc:I mean SSD or some other special filer

Comment: The disk technology will not matter for that aspect.